# PostgreSQL unterminated quoted identifier

Tags: postgresql, groovy, alpine-linux

I have this groovy code which drops a remote postgres schema from commandline:

```
def dropSchema = "psql --dbname=postgres://$user:$pass@localhost:$port/$targetDb -c \"DROP SCHEMA ${applicationName}_${uid} CASCADE;\"".execute()
```

This code is working fine when it's run on a windows machine, but when it's on a Linux distribution, it gives me these errors:

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "appName_uid" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "CASCADE;"" ignored
>
> ERROR:  unterminated quoted identifier at or near ""DROP"
>
> LINE 1: "DROP
>           ^

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `println "psql --dbname=postgres://$user:$pass@localhost:$port/$targetDb -c \"DROP SCHEMA ${applicationName}_${uid} CASCADE;\""` print out?

Comment: @tim_yates this: "psql --dbname=postgres://user:pass@localhost:port/targetDb -c "DROP SCHEMA appName_uid CASCADE;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never ever use a string with `.execute()` like `"ls 'my fancy file'".execute()`.  It splits on *whitespace* and that is most likely never what you want (same as `["ls", "'my", "fancy", "file'"].execute()` for that example).

Also `.execute()` runs the command via the regular `exec` of your OS -- **not the shell**.  So quoting or other things, that needs to be done for a shell command actually make things worse - since no shell is involved to interpret your intention.

Instead use an array, where all params are their own (**don't quote for a shell, that is never used**)

```
[
 "psql", 
 "--dbname=postgres://$user:$pass@localhost:$port/$targetDb", 
 "-c", "DROP SCHEMA ${applicationName}_${uid} CASCADE;"
].execute()
```

If you prefer to reuse an existing shell command, then run it with a shell:

```
["/bin/sh", "-c", "psql ... -c \"DROP ...\" ..."].execute()
```

Here you **have to** quote for the shell, as it is executed like a shell command.

Comment: That worked as you said ! So he is seeing my command as arguments not a single query !

Thanks a lot !